# Spell/Ability Summary Printouts for D&D 5th Ed

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, tool-recommendation

In 4th ed, WotC's character manager printed out character sheets with these awesome spell summary cards. They also had similar summary cards for monsters for the DM. I checked around the site, but unless I just missed it, they don't seem to have anything like that for 5th edition. Does anyone know if there are good options? Even if it was only a PDF template I could fill in and print out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only official product of this type is the [spellbook cards from Gale Force 9](http://www.gf9-dnd.com/gameAcc/tabid/87/entryid/128/Default.aspx). I just got mine (literally yesterday), and they seem pretty good. Some of the more complicated spells have an incomplete summary and a reference to the PHB, and I have heard complaints about them online.

Anything else you might be able to find that includes the full text of spells is probably an illegal product, which I did find some of but I'm not going to link or recommend here.

[This site](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/139323/Tintagels-5E-DD-Card-Template-CORE) offers 5e card templates, which I haven't tried, but they look pretty good if you're willing to do the work of filling them in. Alternatively, it wouldn't be too difficult to make up your own very basic template along similar lines - it might not look as pretty, but it's free.

This is incredibly ugly (I'm not a graphic designer), but it took me less than 5 minutes to make and cost me nothing. If you're already looking at filling your cards out yourself, this really isn't much extra work.

[image: Homemade spell card]

Or if you want to be fancy and have the available resources, you could re-skin the 4e power cards (example below). Depending on how you do it, this does take a little bit of time though, at least initially.

[image: Re-skinned 4e power card]

Comment: I saw the big packs, but that seems like overkill for my use. The templates you linked look perfect and, while not free, $8 is a hard price to argue with. Thanks!

Comment: @Miniman or if they want to be fancy, they can reskin the 4e cards (I've done up an example if you don't mind me adding it [not worth a separate answer]) :p

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Go ahead and add it - if I don't like it I'll just revert it  :P

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Looks good!

Answer (score 3):

**Power2ool a custom item, power, and monster card generator for 4e works perfectly for this**

Since the playtest I've been using [Power2ool](https://power2ool.com/login/) to create 4e style power cards for spells as well as item cards for loot and monster cards while GMing 5th edition. I basically recreated everything in the starter set using power2ool while running it for a group of friends. Power2ool is 100 percent free, signup is quick and the system is easy to use, and automatically formats a group of cards you select to fit pages when you send them to print.

Answer (score 0):

I created this [spell card builder](http://blog.maragnus.com/post/107339915701/dungeons-dragons-5th-edition-spell-card-builder) some time ago for my group.  You can pick and choose what to print. But you need to use IE11 to print them.